# How to remove matrix sub-matrix elements given conditions?

Tags: matlab, matrix, submatrix

I know for a matrix say `mat`, if I want to delete all elements (element-wise) that satisfy certain condition, e.g. remove all zeros, this will do:

```
mat(mat == 0) = [];
```

But how can I do this sub-matrix-wise, i.e. remove matrix sub-matrix elements given conditions. As an example, `data4d` is a 4D matrix with size `n1 x n2 x n3 x n4`. If all the elements of the `i`-th (`1=<i<=n4`) sub-matrix of the fourth dimension, i.e. `data4d(:, :, :, i) == zeros(n1, n2, n3)`, it will be removed, i.e. `data4d(:, :, :, i) = []`.

How can I do these without simple `for` loop? Both the following two version will not work:

```
data4d(data4d == zeros(n1, n2, n3)) = [];      // version 1
data4d(data4d == zeros(n1, n2, n3, 1)) = [];   // version 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One-liner using [any](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/any.html) and [reshape](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```
data4D(:,:,:,~any(reshape(data4D,n1*n2*n3,n4),1)) = [];
```